Error “4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded after 102.893s”
I am encountering a “4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded after 102.893s” error when attempting to upload a large data set to Firestore using a Node.js application hosted on Cloud Run. The error occurs in the middle of the upload process, and although the data eventually writes to Firestore, the process takes an excessive amount of time and consistently results in the deadline exceeded error.
the cloud run configuration is:
Resources:
Memory 8GIB
CPU: 2
Requests:
Timeout 1800 seconds
Maximum concurrent requests per instance 80
CPU is only allocated during request processing
Minimum number of instances 0
Maximum number of instances 25
import { firestore } from "firebase-admin";
import { db } from "../firebase/config";
import { areAllValuesNullOrEmpty } from "./areAllValuesNullOrEmpty";
import { removeNullValues } from "./filterNullValues";

const BATCH_SIZE = 450;
const delay = (ms: number) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

export const uploadToFirestore = async (
  userRefId: string,
  collectionName: string,
  docId: string,
  data: object,
  retries: number = 3,
  delayMs: number = 1000
): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const filteredData = removeNullValues(data);
    if (areAllValuesNullOrEmpty(filteredData)) {
      return;
    }

    const patientRef = db.collection("patients").doc(userRefId);
    const summaryRef = patientRef.collection(collectionName).doc(docId);

    await uploadInBatches(summaryRef, filteredData);

    console.log(`Data uploaded to ${collectionName}/${docId}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to upload data to ${collectionName}/${docId}`, error);

    if (retries > 0) {
      console.log(
        `Retrying upload to ${collectionName}/${docId} (${retries} retries left)...`
      );
      await delay(delayMs);
      await uploadToFirestore(
        userRefId,
        collectionName,
        docId,
        data,
        retries - 1,
        delayMs
      );
    } else {
      console.error(
        `Exhausted retries for uploading data to ${collectionName}/${docId}`
      );
    }
  }
};

const uploadInBatches = async (
  docRef: firestore.DocumentReference,
  data: object
): Promise<void> => {
  const batch = db.batch();
  batch.set(docRef, data);

  await batch.commit();
};

export const uploadActivityToFirestore = async (
  userRefId: string,
  collectionName: string,
  docId: string,
  data: { summary_id: string; [key: string]: any },
  retries: number = 3,
  delayMs: number = 1000
): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const filteredData = removeNullValues(data);
    if (areAllValuesNullOrEmpty(filteredData)) {
      return;
    }

    const patientRef = db.collection("patients").doc(userRefId);
    const summaryRef = patientRef.collection(collectionName).doc(docId);
    const docSnapshot = await summaryRef.get();

    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
      const existingData = docSnapshot.data();
      const activities = existingData?.activities || {};

      activities[filteredData.summary_id] = filteredData;

      await uploadInBatches(summaryRef, { activities });
    } else {
      await uploadInBatches(summaryRef, {
        activities: {
          [filteredData.summary_id]: filteredData,
        },
      });
    }

    console.log(`Data uploaded to ${collectionName}/${docId}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to upload data to ${collectionName}/${docId}`, error);

    if (retries > 0) {
      console.log(
        `Retrying upload to ${collectionName}/${docId} (${retries} retries left)...`
      );
      await delay(delayMs);
      await uploadActivityToFirestore(
        userRefId,
        collectionName,
        docId,
        data,
        retries - 1,
        delayMs
      );
    } else {
      console.error(
        `Exhausted retries for uploading data to ${collectionName}/${docId}`
      );
    }
  }
};


this is an example of when i call the function:
const handleDaily = async (payload: TerraPayload) => {
  const data = payload.data as unknown as Daily[];
  const user = payload.user as unknown as TerraUser;
  const userRefId = user.reference_id;

  for (const dailyData of data) {
    const startTime = dailyData.metadata.start_time;
    const endTime = dailyData.metadata.end_time;
    const collectionId = generateCollectionId(startTime, endTime);

    const collectionsData = generateDailyCollections(dailyData);

    for (const [collectionName, collectionData] of Object.entries(
      collectionsData
    )) {
      await uploadToFirestore(
        userRefId,
        collectionName,
        collectionId,
        collectionData
      );
    }
  }
};


I have tried to bulkwriter, batchwrite and transactions.
Setting delays between requests.
Breaking down data into smaller chunks.
Retrying the upload on failure with a limited number of retries.
I tried some solutions from previous posts but all gives the same result.

As i mentioned the process is taking much time because of the delay which made by this error, and i can see that if this error appears once, all the batches after fails with the same error.
But all the data is coming into Firestore, this means that it was uploaded to Firestore despite the error.
I want to be able to upload the data without any error and I dont know what is causing this problem.

Common problems are missing awaits or hitting limits.
One possibility is that your cloud run is scaling to 0 while request is still being processed.
